# Open Camera Programmatically Through iOS App - Deep Link?

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, ios-camera

I want to create an IBAction to open the iOS native camera app in my app, but I can't seem to find the address for the camera app online.

I know for messages it's: `UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "sms:")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)`

Does anyone know which is the correct scheme?

Comment: FYI - using `open` does not open the requested app "in your app". It launches the app and puts your app in the background.

Comment: @rmaddy that's exactly what i want to do! thanks for letting me know

Comment: It's impossible to lunch the camera app programmatically from your app.

Comment: Is it still impossible to launch the camera app programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to follow a clean way doing so:

```
let cameraVc = UIImagePickerController()
cameraVc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
self.present(cameraVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

in such case you must add into the `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>whatever</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here we suggest you to user the following github :**

https://github.com/shantaramk/AttachmentHandler

!. 1. Drag drop the AttachmentHandler folder in project folder

```
func showCameraActionSheet() {
    AttachmentHandler.shared.showAttachmentActionSheet(viewController: self)
    AttachmentHandler.shared.imagePickedBlock = { (image) in
        let chooseImage = image.resizeImage(targetSize: CGSize(width: 500, height: 600))
        self.imageList.insert(chooseImage, at: self.imageList.count-1)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version, after adding NSCameraUsageDescription in your Info.plist:

```
let cameraVc = UIImagePickerController()
cameraVc.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
self.present(cameraVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```